# Why the string does not split?

Tags: java, regex

While trying to split a string `xyz213123kop234430099kpf4532` into tokens :

```
xyz213123
kop234430099
kpf4532
```

I wrote the following code

```
String s = "xyz213123kop234430099kpf4532";
String regex = "/^[a-zA-z]+[0-9]+$/";
String tokens[] = s.split(regex);
for(String t : tokens) {
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

but instead of tokens, I get the whole string as one output. What is wrong with the *regular expression* I used ?

Comment: I don't think this can be done with `split` and a regular expression, because `split` removes matches of whatever regular expression you search for; but you want your splitting to remove nothing at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that:

```
String s = "xyz213123kop234430099kpf4532";
String[] result = s.split("(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z])");
```

The idea is to use zero width assertions to find the place where to cut the string, then I use a lookbehind (preceded by a digit `[0-9]`) and a lookahead (followed by a letter `[a-z]`).

These lookarounds are just checks and match nothing, thus the delimiter of the split is an empty string and no characters are removed from the result.

Comment: Can you please explain what **I** did and what **you** did ?

Comment: Why didn't the regex that I created split the string ?

Comment: @saplingPro: Your regex doesn't work because it is anchored with `^` and `$`. The second reason is: with `[a-z]+[0-9]+` as delimiter, all your string will be seen as a succession of delimiters between empty strings.

Comment: Okay. Why shouldn't I use `^` and `$` ? I use this in _javascript_

Comment: It means the same in Javascript as it means in Java.  ^ means beginning of the WHOLE STRING.  $ means end of the WHOLE STRING.  By definition, you can't FIND these things in the middle of your string.  So you shouldn't try to split on any regular expression that contains ^ or $.

Comment: @saplingPro: Your pattern will not work in javascript too. This is what your pattern say:"at the begining of the string, there is 1 or more letters, followed by 1 or more digits and the end of the string". This description doesn't exist in your string.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I see. I thought I was delimiting a token by using `^` and `$`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte If I change the string to `@xyz213123!kop234430099#kpf4532` and regex to `/[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+/`, then also the string doesn't split. Now I expect the string to split as `@`,`!`,`#`

Comment: @saplingPro: java regexes don't use delimiters (`/`) as in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You could split on this matching between a number and not-a-number.

```
String s = "xyz213123kop234430099kpf4532";
String[] parts = s.split("(?<![^\\d])(?=\\D)");
for (String p : parts) {
   System.out.println(p);
}
```

Output

```
xyz213123
kop234430099
kpf4532
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in your string that matches the regular expression, because your expression starts with ^ (beginning of string) and ends with $ (end of string).  So it would either match the whole string, or nothing at all.  But because it doesn't match the string, it is not found when you split the string into tokens.  That's why you get just one big token.

Comment: Well that was obvious ! I think I am misinterpreting the `regex`. Doesn't it mean `start with alphabets and end with numbers` ?

Comment: It means have some letters, then have some numbers.  But not a mixture.  It has to be all the letters first, then all the numbers.

Comment: If so, why doesn't the string split. `Regex` just tells the way I want the string to split

Comment: Because NOTHING in your string matches {beginning of the whole string}-{some letters}-{some numbers}-{end of the whole string}.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `split` for that. The argument to `split` is the *delimiter between* tokens. You don't have that. Instead, you have a pattern that repeats and you want each match to the pattern. Try this instead:

```
String s = "xyz213123kop234430099kpf4532";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-z]+[0-9]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

> xyz213123
>   kop234430099
>   kpf4532

(I don't know by what logic you would have the second token be "3kop234430099" as in your posted question. I assume that the leading "3" is a typo.)

Comment: that was a typo. But I didn't get you on not using the `split` method. If you can be more clear as the documentation about split says `Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.`

Comment: Say you had a string "123456789". So you could `split` this string around matches of a regex "4", to give the substrings "123" and "56789".

Comment: @Pines I just don't get the feeling when I think the regular expression I created to be a _delimiter_ too.

Comment: @saplingPro - `split()` treats the delimiter as something _between_ tokens; it is not part of the returned array. However, I overstated things when I said not to use `split`. You can indeed use it to return the entire string divided into pieces if you can find an appropriate zero-width delimiter. One answer here show how you can use a zero-width negative look-behind pattern to do this and another used both look-behind and look-ahead. The patterns are zero width (do not match any of the text itself); instead, they match positions at which surrounding text matches a pattern.